# Eclipse Force IDE: Found read only local file content not in sync with remote instance. Use Synchronize to resolve conflict.

Tags: eclipse, ide, ant, xml, force.com-ide

I am trying to update the leads object with new fields I created using force ide. However, whenever I try I get the following error: Eclipse Force IDE: Found read only local file content not in sync with remote instance. Use Synchronize to resolve conflict.

I have tried to right click on the xml and selecting the synchronize with server option but after I do and attempt to save these fields to the server this problem still persists.

Please help [image]

Comment: What is the version of your Eclipse

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue earlier with Eclipse Kepler version.

I tried to use Eclipse Mars version and It fixed it. Try using Eclipse mars ,